# With Rails, how can I query the db for an aggregate number and grouped by week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given a table like so:

**Log:**

```
id, user_id, points, created_at
```

With Rails, how can I query the database by user_id and then GROUPED by week via created_at where I can then having something like:

```
   WEEK of X/XX/XXXX - 3011 total points
   WEEK of X/XX/XXXX - 320 total points
   WEEK of X/XX/XXXX - 31 total points
   WEEK of X/XX/XXXX - 30330 total points
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using postgresql you can do this: `User.all.group("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").` But that only gets you halfway there.

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: `Log.sum(:points).group("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").where(user_id: user_id)` should do it for `postgres`. If you are using another database you will have to determine how to handle the grouping into weeks.

Comment: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
points_by_week = Log.where(user_id: user_id).group("DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at)", "DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").sum(:points)
```

Will yield a result like

```
{[2014, 4]=>3,
 [2014, 8]=>7,
 [2015, 4]=>26,
 [2015, 6]=>19,
 [2015, 12]=>50,
 [2015, 32]=>48,
 [2016, 2]=>78,
 [2016, 3]=>45,
 [2016, 4]=>49,
 [2016, 5]=>110,
 [2016, 45]=>30,
 [2017, 4]=>130,
 [2017, 11]=>185}
```

where the key is [year, week], then you can use Date.commercial to get the week of

```
points_by_week.each do |(year, week), count|
  date = Date.commercial(year, week)
  puts "Week of #{date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} - #{count} total points"
end
```

And (just cause I can), the mysql version of the query looks like this

```
points_by_week = Log.where(user_id: user_id).group("year(created_at)", "week(created_at)").sum(:points)
```

This by default assumes the week starts on Monday, and the first week of a year is starts on the first Monday of the year

Comment: This is great - thank you! FYI, there was an error due to a comma missing after `DATE_TRUNC('week' `

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
points_by_week = Log.select("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) as week, sum(points) as total_points").group("week").where(user_id: x)

points_by_week.each do |pw|
  puts "Week of #{pw.week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} - #{pw.total_points} total points"
end
```

**EDIT**

as per Michael Gorman comment the above won't distinguish between years (2017, 2016, etc), so you might need to group by week and year depending on your requirements:

```
Log.select("DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) as week, DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at) as year, sum(points) as total_points").group("week, year")
```

and you can keep using the above loop to display it ;)

Comment: This query will not distinguish between week 1 2016 and week 1 2017

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select 'WEEK of ' || TO_CHAR(date_trunc( 'week', created_at ), 'dd/mm/yyyy') || ' - ' || sum(points) || ' total points'
FROM clients
  WHERE id < 100000
  GROUP BY date_trunc( 'week', created_at );
```

[`||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) is used to concatenate string.

[`TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html) is used as a data type formatting functions.